# Why does readline on Popen.stdout block?

Tags: python, subprocess, buffer

So I'm working on a python script that has to communicate with an executable that (exactly like the python interpreter) has an interactive shell. I found some description of similar scenarios with solutions, but none of them seem to solve my problem.
I tried to write good object orientated code that does the trick. But when I try to read from the stdout of a subprocess the Interpreter gets stuck forever and I do not understand why. Here is my code:

This is main.py:

```
import subprocess_wrapper as sw

print("Will start now.")

python = "python3"

proc = sw.SubprocessWrapper(python)
print("Output: ", proc.get_next_output())
print("------------")
```

This is subprocess_wrapper.py

```
import subprocess as sb
import os
from time import sleep

class SubprocessWrapper(sb.Popen):

    def __init__(self, p_executable_filename):
        self.executable_filename = p_executable_filename
        super(SubprocessWrapper, self).__init__(self.executable_filename, stdin=sb.PIPE, stdout=sb.PIPE, shell=True)

    def get_next_output(self):
        next_output = ""
        input_lines = 0

        while input_lines < 1:
            new_line = self.stdout.readline().decode()
            next_output += new_line
            if new_line.startswith('>'):
                input_lines += 1

            self.stdout.flush()

        return next_output

    def write(self, p_input):
        print("Passing {} to subprocess.".format(p_input))
        self.stdin.write('{}\n'.format(p_input).encode())
        self.stdin.flush()
        print("Done passing.")
```

**What I try to do with this:**
As when the python interpreter waits for user input it indicates this by printing ">>>". Therefore the get_next_output method should return everything in the stdout buffer until it reads ">" at the beginning of some line.

**What happens:**
The program gets stuck the moment it reaches the readline() line. As far as I know, readline() blocks until something is written into the buffer. This is good, since i don't want to waist cpu time reading the buffer when its empty. Some solutions I found use fcntl to change the blocking flag of the buffer. But this should not be necessary in my case, because i actually want to wait for something to be written into it.

**My questions:**
1. Why exactly does the readline() block forever, even when there should be written something into it.
2. How do I have to modify my code to work as expected without losing the performance benefits of a blocking buffer (to avoid active waiting).

Comment: you can use fcntl to not just make stdout not block but also to change how it buffers data. usually stdout is line buffered, meaning you only get output from a process after each newline (`'\n'`) have you tried removing the line buffering with fcntl to see if it solves your problem?

Comment: I will try to find out how to remove the linebuffering, but I'm not sure if this will fix the problem as calling python3 prints multiple lines for me.